# Why is it returning as ‘send’ of undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I set up the code below just like my `guildMemberAdd`, that is working fine however the code below doesn’t.

It give me

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined

when I have the correct channel defined. I’m not sure why.

```
client.on("guildMemberRemove", function(message) {
  let guild = message.guild;
  let member = message;
  let memberCount = message.guild.memberCount
    let memmChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "logs");
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setColor("#da7272")
      .setThumbnail(member.user.displayAvatarURL({ format: 'png', dynamic: true }))
      .setDescription(`${member.user} just left the lobby.\n\nMember Count: \`#${message.guild.memberCount}\``);

    memmChannel.send(embed);
});
```

Comment: `message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "logs")` returns `undefined`. I would guess the predicate doesn't match anything.

Comment: How does it not match anything if I have a channel called, `logs`?

Comment: `console.log(memmChannel)` does it output anything?

Answer (score 0):

It means the bot could not find any channel with name "logs".
I think this is due to the fact that the member is no longer in the guild.

You should try to log your `message.guild`, analyze the output, and adapt your code using the results. For example, using the guild id, if it exists to run a `const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(GuildID)`.

If you could send what the output of `console.log(message.guild)` is like, I think I should be able to help you to resolve your problem :)